# no corre tensorflow

Tags: jupyter, anaconda, tensorflow, keras

por si alguién a tenido este problema y lo pudo solucionar.

cargue anaconda y cree dos ambientes, el base(root) y tensorflow, active tensorflow y keras, sin embargo al usar jupyter resuelve solo con el ambiente base(root) y no usa para la parte de redes neuronales el segundo ambiente, tensorflow-keras, indicando que no están cargados tensorflow y keras, estandolos en este segundo ambientes.

Que puedo hacer para resolver que vaya al segundo ambientes "tensorflow" jupyter?

gracias, Emilio

Answer (score 0):

Cuando estás en Jupyter, puedes acceder a kernel y cambiar el kernel (change kernel) al que tú desees. Aquí te dejo una foto, para que lo veas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

muchas gracias por la sugerencia. Finalmente lo resolví de la siguiente forma: cree un ambiente en anaconda y en cargué todas las librerías que requiero usar incluido el tensorflow y keras.

Gracias nuevamente por contestar, si alguien tiene esta dificultad me puede preguntar los detalles.